# Program works in Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 but not in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: binary

I have been using a program called movie thumbnailer (mtn) for many years.

Read about the program here: http://moviethumbnail.sourceforge.net/

I have downloaded the following binary: https://sourceforge.net/projects/moviethumbnail/files/movie%20thumbnailer%20linux%20binary/mtn-200808a-linux/

I have downloaded a live iso file for Ubuntu 17.04, 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and started them in Virtual Box. To exclude it only happens in my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

When running the program using the terminal in Ubuntu 17.04/17.10 I get this (works):
[image]

When running the program using the terminal in Ubuntu 18.04 I get this:
[image]

Is there anybody who can tell me why this happens in Ubuntu 18.04 and how I get the program to work in Ubuntu 18.04.

The program has not been updated since 2008, but has worked fine until Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: `The program has not been updated since 2008, but has worked fine until Ubuntu 18.04.` Perhaps this is the issue as bionic is now gnome!

Comment: 17.10 was also gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options here:

- Get newer version from [new BitBucket repository](https://gitlab.com/movie_thumbnailer/mtn/tags):

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://bitbucket.org/wahibre/mtn/downloads/mtn_3.3_ubuntu18_amd64.deb
  sudo apt-get install ./mtn_3.3_ubuntu18_amd64.deb
  ```

  It launches normally:

  ```
  $ mtn
  mtn: no input files or directories specified

  Movie Thumbnailer (mtn) 3.3
  Compiled with: Lavc57.107.100 Lavf57.83.100 Lavu55.78.100 SwS4.8.100 GD:2.2.5
  ...
  ```
- Try to get build dependencies with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libgd-dev
  ```

  then patch source code to reflect modern changes of the APIs.
- Create [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) with previous (but supported) Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version and launch your application here:

  First of all get the software:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://datapacket.dl.sourceforge.net/project/moviethumbnail/movie%20thumbnailer%20linux%20binary/mtn-200808a-linux/mtn-200808a-linux.tgz
  tar -xf mtn-200808a-linux.tgz
  cd mtn-200808a-linux/
  ```

  then setup schroot:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/xenial.conf
  [xenial]
  description=Ubuntu 16.04
  directory=/srv/chroot/xenial
  root-users=$USER
  type=directory
  users=$USER
  EOF

  sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/xenial
  sudo debootstrap xenial /srv/chroot/xenial

  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/xenial/etc/apt/sources.list
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
  EOF
  ```

  (it will end with small 250 Mb `/srv/chroot/xenial` folder).

  then run your application:

  ```
  user@bionic:~/Downloads/mtn-200808a-linux$ schroot -c xenial 
  (xenial)user@bionic:~/Downloads/mtn-200808a-linux$ ./mtn 
  mtn: no input files or directories specified

  movie thumbnailer (mtn) 200808a copyright (c) 2007-2008 tuit, et al.
  ...
  ```

Comment: During my search on how to make a new built as proposed, I found someone who had already done this. 

If others have the same problem, they can download a new version here: 
https://gitlab.com/movie_thumbnailer/mtn/tags

Comment: I added deb-file from your link as the first possible method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest **workaround** would be to export a locale before running mtn. 
For ex. here with english in the terminal instance that's to run mtn go

`export LANG=/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8`

Then run your command for mtn in that same terminal.

Edit: actually i *think* it may just be the location? as this would also work..

`export LANG=/usr/lib/locale/`

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with language or time settings? 

I have tried both suggestions but it does not change anything.